# All except PHP alternative to switch?

Tags: php

So I am writing a webpage that calls a PHP script. The array grabs data from the jQuery for the php to deal with.

Now what I need to do is the script to run all those includes *except* the `$pageException`.  For example if `$pageException` is `contact-us`, `contact-us.php` should not be included.

Obviously I could achieve this using a switch statement and for the below example provide three different cases, but I feel their may be an easier way.

I'm betting i'm forgetting about something that is blatantly obvious here but it just doesn't come to mind...

```
$new_address = $_POST['address'];

function pageData($pageException) { 
    include("about-us.php");
    include("contact-us.php");
    include("who-we-are.php");
}

pageData ($new_address);
```

Comment: Make an array of files to include, then remove the one you don't want.

Comment: I am missing something obvious here, but are you looking for the `default:` in a switch statement - which is what is used if nothing else matches?

Answer (score 6):

How about an array?

```
$pages = array('about-us.php', 'contact-us.php', 'who-we-are.php');

foreach($pages as $page) {
    if($page !== $pageException) {
        require $page;
    }
}
```

Comment: nice, i think this might be what I was looking for, let me get back to you

Comment: In this scenario it might work well to define the array directly in the foreach by the way (ie `foreach(array('about-us.php', 'contact-us.php', 'who-we-are.php') as $page)` )

Answer (score 0):

Store your includes in an array, and do the include by looping over that array, only execute the include if the page is not equal to the exception:

```
function pageData($pageException) { 
    $pages = array("about-us.php", "contact-us.php", "who-we-are.php");

    foreach($pages as $page){
        if($page !== $pageException){
            include($page);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You'll need a `global $pages;` there.

Comment: I was just illustrating the point, depends on what the rest of his code looks like I think. Probably better to keep it inside the function, I'll edit.